# Top authors or top categories by post views?

Tags: plugins

Is it possible to show top authors by post views or top categories by post views?
Have been looking for a plugin but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can try

1. Update post meta each time a post is visited
2. Query with the meta key and author and calculate the top author you can find the top author by date like month, days or even custom dates.

If you don't know how to do these, then you can hire some experts for this.